# SQL: value higher than percentage of population of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to calculate the value which is higher than a percentage of the population of values, this per group.

Suppose I have:

```
CREATE TABLE project
(
    id int,
    event int, 
    val int
);

INSERT INTO project(id,event,val) 
VALUES
    (1, 11, 43), 
    (1, 12, 19), 
    (1, 13, 19),
    (1, 14, 53),
    (1, 15, 45),
    (1, 16, 35),
    (2, 21, 22),
    (2, 22, 30),
    (2, 23, 25),
    (2, 24, 28);
```

I now want to calculate for each id what is the val that will be for example higher than 5%, or 30% of the val for that id.

For example, for id=1, we have the following values: 43, 19, 19, 53, 45, 35.
So the contingency table would look like this:

```
19 35 43 45 53 
 2  1  1  1  1
```

and the val=20 (higher than 19) would be chosen to be higher than 5% (actuall 2 out of 6) of the rows.

The contengency table for id 2 is:

```
22 25 28 30
 1  1  1  1
```

My expected out is:

```
id  val_5p_coverage  val_50p_coverage
1   20               36
2   23               26
```

val_5p_coverage is the value val needed to be above at least 5% of val in the id.

val_50p_coverage is the value val needed to be above at least 50% of val in the id.

How can I calculate this with SQL ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: the reason there is no answer is because it is not clear what you are trying to do (some expected output would be good) and what you have tried that has failed.  This is not a "get a free consultant to write it for you" service.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it in *HiveQL* (for Hadoop) as follows:

```
create table prep as
    select *,
            CUME_DIST() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val ASC) as proportion_val_equal_or_lower
    from project

SELECT id,
       MIN(IF(proportion_val_equal_or_lower>=0.05, val, NULL)) AS val_5p_coverage,
       MIN(IF(proportion_val_equal_or_lower>=0.50, val, NULL)) AS val_50p_coverage
FROM prep
GROUP BY id
```

Although this is not MySQL nor SQL per se, it might help to do it in MySQL or SQL.